# Execute command every time I press Enter until I press a key to quit in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm not familiar with Batch and I want to do a very simple thing that I can't find online.

I want to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
while(shift is not pressed)
    python file.py
    PAUSE
```

Basically I want to run the `file.py` and then `PAUSE` so that I can press `Enter` and it will be executed again. When I press `Shift`, it would close the cmd.

So far I have done this to simulate the loop:

```
python file.py
PAUSE
python file.py
PAUSE
python file.py
PAUSE
(...)
python file.py
PAUSE
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking about `bash`, or windows `cmd`, since you have both tags.

Comment: @cody: The goal is to have this in a `.bat` file and run it so that it will be executed in the windows command line.

Comment: Understood, in that case the `bash` tag is unnecessary, I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Looping is trivial. But there is no native batch command or utility to detect whether the shift key is pressed.

You could easily use SET /P or CHOICE instead of PAUSE to request input that you can take action on.

```
@echo off
:loop
python file.py
choice /m Again
if not errorlevel 2 goto :loop
```

The above code will issue the following prompt after each execution (assuming English):

```
Again [Y,N]?
```

The code will loop if Y is pressed, and exit if N is pressed.